# How do I fix "model build step failed" error for mcode (under "mrgsolve" package)? And what does the warning message " 'make' not found" mean?

Tags: r, compiler-errors, package, installation

I wish to run a model for a code using the package "mrgsolve". To compile the model I would use the function mcode(), but it would produce the warning message and error in question. Perhaps there is something I'm missing during the package installation?

In short, I have followed the instructions on installing mrgsolve as closely I could: https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/mrgsolve/wiki/mrgsolve-Installation

Here are all of the packages I have loaded included mrgsolve:

```
library(processx)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("r-lib/pkgbuild", force = TRUE)
library(pkgbuild)
library(githubinstall)
library(installr)
library(mrgsolve)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# model

rcode_2cmt <- "
  $PARAM
  CL=0.4
  V1=3.87
  Q=0.609
  V2=4.11

  $SET
  delta=0.1, end=600

  $CMT CENT PERI

  $MAIN

  double K10 = CL/V1 ;
  double K12 = Q/V1 ;
  double K21 = Q/V2 ;

  $ODE
  dxdt_CENT= -K10*CENT - K12*CENT + K21*PERI ;
  dxdt_PERI= K12*CENT-K21*PERI;


  $TABLE
  double CP=CENT/V1;

  $CAPTURE
  CP 
"

# to compile the model:

model_2cmt <- mcode("2cmt", code = rcode_2cmt) #where error occurs
model_2cmt
```

From my understanding, running model_2cmt should then produce the model in the form of a ggplot, or so I gather from example("mrgsolve").

But here is my current error output:

Building 2cmt ... error.

---:: stdout ::---------------------------------------------

---:: stderr ::---------------------------------------------
Warning message:

### In system(cmd) : 'make' not found

Error: The model build step failed.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me recently. I first downloaded the newest Rtools package (which is Rtools40) here https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Then I made sure to update R to the newest version. After that, I think you should be good. It's a weird path thing that I can never really fully understand (lol) but just doing as simple as these two steps fixed the problem for me.